# How can I merge using a custom merge-base?

Tags: git

My repository contains some accidents: Branch A was (poorly) merged into B, then those changes were reverted and then B was merged to master.

Branch A even though it contains a new feature is merged into master without the features.

```
git checkout master
git merge A
```

does nothing.

```
git checkout A
git merge master
```

fast forwards to master HEAD.

How can I "merge" master and A with a custom merge-base basically ignoring that they already were merged?

Comment: If the repository belongs entirely to you, why not completely back out the merges and the revert and start over?

Comment: The accident happened in a PR from a fork. While I would guess that the author who did not merge one but three of my WIP branches intermixed with commits `messier`, `messiest` and `Oops. That wasn't meant to happen` might be fine with this, I'd rather not have to force-change across forks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't, but you don't need to.  Just make a *new* "copy of A" branch and merge that.  We'll see an easy way to do that at the end, using `git rebase`.

The long answer notes that actually, you *can*, through careful use of `git replace` to build a synthetic history (or by running `git merge-recursive`: this is easier in one sense, but not designed for users to invoke directly).  Just what needs replacing requires some analysis, and potentially a lot of very careful analysis.  This allows you to run `git merge` to achieve a particular result ... but that result is supported only by the crafted, synthetic history built through `git replace`, and that synthetic history generally won't go into new repositories.  So that's a lot of work that in the end isn't really used, except for the one `git merge` step, which means: *why bother?*

(Sometimes the `git replace` trick is easy, and then you might want to do that for aesthetics.  That is, do the replace and merge, instead of the workaround I'll show.  But I'd argue that the copy-of-branch-A is better anyway.)

#### Why do we bother with merges anyway?

Before we jump into the mechanics of merging, let's look at the *results* of merging.  This helps us get to the "why bother" part.  Let's start with a typical case where merging is actually required, i.e., when we have a commit graph that looks like this:

```
          I--J   <-- ours (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- theirs
```

That is, we're on a branch named `ours`, whose last commit has some big ugly hash ID that we'll just call "commit `J`".  We picked up someone else's work, which we have on a branch we call `theirs`, whose last commit has some different big ugly hash ID we will call `L`.

> Sidebar: Each commit holds a *snapshot of all files*, plus some metadata.  The metadata include the hash ID of its predecessor or *parent* commit.  So our commit `J` remembers the hash ID of our earlier commit `I`, which remembers the hash ID of still-earlier commit `H`.  Their commit `L` remembers the hash ID of their commit `J` which remembers the hash ID of still-earlier commit `H`.
>
> This all means that both we and they started from a common starting point, which is commit `H`.  Commit `H` holds a snapshot of all files, and so do each of the other commits.  Git can compare the snapshot *in* commit `H` against the snapshot in any other commit.

The *job* for `git merge` is to combine changes:

- We started from commit `H`—the shared common starting point, which `git merge` calls the *merge base*—and made some changes and committed a new snapshot `I`.  Then we made more changes and committed our last snapshot `J`.  If we have Git compare the snapshot `H` against our snapshot `J`, that will tell Git—and us—what we changed: which files we modified, and for each file that we did modify, what lines we removed and what lines we added, with what text on them.
- At the same time, they started from commit `H` and made changes, and (either by happy coincidence, or from cheating by the author of this answer to make the diagram pretty ) also made two commits.  If we have Git compare `H` vs `L`, we'll find out what *they* changed.

Git can then combine these two sets of changes—with luck, all on its own—and apply the combined changes to the snapshot in commit `H`.  That way, we keep our work, and also add in their work.  I like to refer to this phase of `git merge` as *merge as a verb:* it's the action of combining sets of changes.

As you've more or less noted in your question, one problem here—though it's normally a big *advantage*, actually—is that *Git* picks the merge base commit on its own.  Git uses the commit graph to do this, and a computer algorithm called [Lowest Common Ancestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor), because finding a good merge base is pretty hard in real graphs, which are rarely tidy like the one I drew.

Once Git has done all of this merging on its own, without stopping in the middle due to a merge conflict, `git merge` will normally go on to make a *merge commit*, which we can draw like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- ours (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- theirs
```

Commit `M` here, which letter somehow coincidentally is the first letter of the word "merge", has not just one but *two* parents.  The first parent is the usual parent: commit `J`, where our branch was pointing a moment ago.  The second parent is the other commit that we merged.  Other than the two parents, though, commit `M` is just like any other commit, in that it has a full snapshot of every file.  This full snapshot *is* the correct result of the merge, as far as Git is concerned anyway.

I like to refer to this as *merge as a noun or adjective*, because here we use the word *merge* to modify the noun *commit*, or as a standalone noun that is shorthand for the two-word phrase, *merge commit*.  The merge commit `M` serves to change the *future merge base* of a *future merge*.  This is both its strength—by fixing any merge conflicts that do arise, we usually make sure they don't arise again later for instance—and its weakness.  Whatever we put into `M` is right, and Git is sure of that, even if it turns out that we got it wrong.

#### This leads us to your exact problem

> Branch A was (poorly) merged into B, then those changes were reverted and then B was merged to master.

Git is really about *commits*, not branches—but commits include these parent linkages, and the collection of commits, and the graph that this forms, make up something that people call branches.  This ambiguous use of the word *branch* means that the above sentence makes sense—but also that we should *draw* the situation, even if we simplify it a bit, because humans use the word *branch* to mean *branch names* sometimes.  So let's draw it:

```
...--*--...--o---------...----------N   <-- master
      \       \                    /
       \       B1--B2--M--B3--W--B4   <-- branch-B
        \             /
         A1---...---An   <-- branch-A
```

Commit `M` was the merge of `A1--...--An` into the `B` series of commits.

Commit `W`—`W` looks like an upside-down `M`; I stole this from Linus Torvalds—was the `git revert -m1` of commit `M`.  Its purpose was to back out the "bad merge" `M`.  The problem here is that while the *snapshot* is undone, i.e., the revert in `W` backs out the incorrect merge that was in `M`, the *history* remains: commits `A1` through `An` are all ancestors of `M` and are therefore ancestors of `B4` and hence ancestors of `N`.

This is *why* Git thinks that the merge is already done.  A:

```
git checkout master && git merge branch-A
```

says there is nothing at all to do.  A:

```
git checkout branch-A && git merge master  # or git merge --no-ff master
```

computes the merge base of commit `N` and commit `An` as being commit `An`: no actual merging is required, and without `--no-ff` you get a fast-forward.  Adding `--no-ff` doesn't have a *useful* effect as Git compares `An` to `An` for one set of changes, and therefore finds no changes from the whole `A` series of commits.

Your question is: *How do we convince `git merge` to use commit `*` as the merge base?*  That would achieve the correct merge this time.  In this particular case, where there's only the one merge `M`, we could use `git replace` to splice in a temporary fake replacement-`M` commit that has only one parent, `B2`, instead of two parents.  That would do the job, after which we could remove the `git replace` replacement.  But it's a little tricky.  We could also set a bunch of environment variables the way the `git merge` front end does, then invoke `git merge-recursive` directly, supplying all the right arguments, as this allows us to pick the merge base commit directly.  But there's another way.

#### What if we have an easy way to *copy* all the `A` commits?

Suppose we could take this graph:

```
...--*--...--o---------...----------N   <-- master
      \       \                    /
       \       B1--B2--M--B3--W--B4   <-- branch-B
        \             /
         A1---...---An   <-- branch-A
```

and produce a new `branch-C` that looks like this:

```
       C1--...--Cn   <-- branch-C
      /
...--*--...--o---------...----------N   <-- master
      \       \                    /
       \       B1--B2--M--B3--W--B4   <-- branch-B
        \             /
         A1---...---An   <-- branch-A
```

We can now `git checkout master && git merge branch-C`.  This will achieve what you wanted, and has very low cost: the N commits `C1-...-Cn` on branch-C all re-use the snapshots from the corresponding N commits on branch-A.  They have different *hash IDs* though, and therefore Git sees them as different, unmerged commits.  The merge base of this `C` series of commits *is* commit `*`, which is the one you've been wanting.

So, how *do* we get `branch-C`?  The answer is to use `git rebase`:

```
git checkout -b branch-C branch-A
git rebase -f <hash-of-commit-*>
```

The `checkout` command creates the new name, `branch-C`, pointing to existing commit `An`.  The `git rebase` command tells Git to copy `A1` through `An` to where they are now.  Normally `git rebase` would just say: *Hey, that's a big no-op, I'm not going to copy anything.*  But we use the `-f` option (which we can spell as `--no-ff` or `--force-rebase` as well), which tells Git to shut up and stop being so clever and *copy* those commits.  So when we're done we have exactly what we want.  Now we can:

```
git checkout master && git merge branch-C
```

and that does exactly what we want, *and* leaves a record of this re-merge, with the extra copy of the branch.  If appropriate (I think it is appropriate but whoever does the merge gets to decide this), the person doing the merge can include a comment noting that this is a sort of re-merge, pointing to the earlier merge and its revert to explain why branch-C came into existence in the first place.

Comment: Wow, you put a lot of work into this answer. Thanks for that.